# Python - Using socket.gethostbyname through proxy

Tags: python, sockets, proxy, tor

I'm using TOR to proxy connections but am having difficulty proxying DNS lookups via `socket.gethostbyname("www.yahoo.com")` -- I learned that it was not sending DNS traffic via proxy by sniffing traffic with wireshark.  Here's a copy of the code I'm using

```
import StringIO
import socket
import socks  # SocksiPy module
import stem.process
from stem.util import term

SOCKS_PORT = 7000

socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, '127.0.0.1', SOCKS_PORT)

socket.socket = socks.socksocket

def getaddrinfo(*args):
    return [(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 6, '', (args[0], args[1]))]
socket.getaddrinfo = getaddrinfo

socket.gethostbyname("www.yahoo.com") <--- This line is not sending traffic via proxy
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can change the way your application links to the socket library using something like torsocks. Using this tool will cause your application to link to tor socket library instead of regular socket library without any work on your part.

Comment: For those of you who want to use the socket module instead of another module (such as socks, or requests) to connect through a proxy see this question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32792333/python-socket-module-connecting-to-an-http-proxy-then-performing-a-get-request/42913875

Answer (score 7):

You're calling `gethostbyname` in the `socket` module.  It doesn't know anything about your `SOCKS` socket; it is simply interacting with your operating system's name resolution mechanisms.  Setting `socket.socket = socks.socksocket` may affect network connections made through the `socket` module, but the module does not make direct connections to DNS servers to perform name resolution so replacing `socket.socket` has no impact on this behavior.

If you simply call the `connect(...)` method on a `socks.socksocket` object using a hostname, the proxy will perform name resolution via `SOCKS`:

```
s = socks.socksocket()
s.connect(('www.yahoo.com', 80))
```

If you actually want to perform raw DNS queries over your `SOCKS` connection, you'll need to find a Python DNS module to which you can provide your `socksocket` object.

Comment: but how do you get the address from this connection? `s.getpeername()` will annoyingly return the unresolved `('www.yahoo.com', 80)`

Answer (score 1):

If you resolve the DNS yourself with Socks5 you may leak information about your own computer. Instead try tunneling with Proxifier, then to Tor. Alternatively you can use SocksiPy's Socks4A extension. This will make sure information is not leaked.