# How to use sockets (or socks) with a proxy and send data from that proxy to a website?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, proxy, socks

So as mentioned in the title I want to be able to send data to an ip anonymously through a proxy using the sockets module.. or the socks module.. (i know that this can be done with different modules but i want this specific one because i can better understand it)

i have used the socks module as shown below.. but i always get an error saying "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".. i have tried a number of different proxies an got no luck.. so im thinking that im doing something wrong here.. any ideas?

```
import socks

Socket=socks.socksocket()

Socket.setproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4,"(ProxyIP)",(ProxyPort))
Socket.connect(("(WebsiteIP or Domain Name)",(WebsitePort)))
Socket.close()
print ("connected")
```

Also i have tried this but got the same error
[Python socket module. Connecting to an HTTP proxy then performing a GET request on an external resource](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32792333/18196685)