# DNS Request over SOCKS5 using Python 3

Tags: python, proxy, dns, socks

I have to make a DNS request using python 3 over a SOCKS 5 proxy. (consequently **NO DNS requests are made from my ip address**, the socks5 proxy does it for me and should respond with the according A/AAA records or nothing/something else if it can not resolve it)

**I found the following github projects:**

*rthalley/dnspython*: no proxy/socks support

*Anorov/PySocks*: no ipv6, no possiblity to receive the remote DNS response

**I found the following stackoverflow thread**:
[Python - Using socket.gethostbyname through proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529589/python-using-socket-gethostbyname-through-proxy)
-> It uses pysocks, which has no ipv6 support -> not useable for me

Do you have any idea how to accomplish my task?

Comment: Poor man solution: ssh port redirection with Socks support (see `-D` option)

Comment: Also, why specifically Socks? Nowadays you have DNS over HTTPS and DNS over TLS, services also provided by some big public resolvers, so that may be easier options.

Answer (score 7):

It's surprisingly easy. It works the same way as in curl:

If you need DNS to be resolved **client side**, use `socks5://host:port` syntax

If you need DNS to be resolved on the **proxy side**, use `socks5h://host:port` syntax

Answer (score 0):

in the lin 45 of query.py

```
# Function used to create a socket.  Can be overridden if needed in special
# situations.
socket_factory = socket.socket
```

you can reset the socket_factory value(use PySocks)